# async pipe as not working within an input in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm used to use the async pipe with "as" in an Angular HTML template to avoid replicating observable subscriptions, like this:

```
<component *ngIf="(selected$ | async) as selected"></component>
```

So then I can use "selected" anywhere else in the template.

But then if I try to use it like this, in an input:

```
<component [param]="(selected$ | async) as selected"></component>
```

I get an error:

```
Unexpected token 'as' at column 21 in [categories$ | async as categories]
```

Any idea why?
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's correct, the `as` syntax is specific to `*ngIf`. It's not a general keyword you can use anywhere in Angular templates.

See https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf and search for `NgIfAs` class.

Comment: How do I use a async var to disable a button. Do we need to use a function?

Answer (score 2):

As already martin says `as` syntax is specific to `*ngIf`. But you can use `ng-container` to get results that you want:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(selected$ | async) as selected">
    <component [param]="selected"></component>
</ng-container>
```